# VSTS release management transform web.config

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am using the new VSTS release management to deploy my website to Azure web app. All I want is to transform one connection string for QA environment. I am finding it hard to get answer for that. Any help is much appreciated.

I don't want to create tokens in my web config file because I want to use the config file as such in my local environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the VSTS variable which contains the connectionstring to deploy as a connectionstring to an Azure WebApp.

This looks like a shameless plug for my open source VSTS task. But it is a clean and easy solution for your problem. My task can be used to deploy appsettings and connectionstrings configured as variables in VSTS to deploy to an Azure webapp. Without changing the web.config.

Take a look in the marketplace to install it in VSTS and for the documentation: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pascalnaber.PascalNaber-Xpirit-WebAppConfiguration

Comment: Thanks pascal. I didn't realize azure websites pick up the connection string from the portal app settings. I was wondering why your task wasn't updating the web.config file. But it was updating the portal setting. If azure websites pick it from the portal why do we need variables? They can be once setup in the portal and left like that. Would like to know your thoughts on that.

Comment: There are multiple reasons why you may want to have a variable which contains the connectionstring, instead of a value hard coded in the azure portal. It depends for example on the extend to which you apply Continuous Delivery. Developers do not have to got access to the production Azure webapp. But the VSTS release can have that through a Service Principal.

Answer (score 2):

Storing connection strings (other than the local dev ones) on a source control is far from being a best practice from a security perspective.
The build/release management system allows you to have secret variables and/or services endpoints you can reuse in your flow.
However you should look into the publish commutator in the build step (MSBuild arguments), that will ask to visual studio to do the publish and apply transformations from the config transform files and publishing profile.
`/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.stagingDirectory)"`

Comment: thanks for your reply. I want to update the config files with the environment variables defined in the VSTS release management for a given environment. I need help in doing that. Have you tried and got that to work?

Comment: at this point of the flow (deployment) the config transform using web.BuildConfig.config should be already done.  
however you can use some "scripting" in the azure deployment step to do that like `-connectionString @{"$(ConnectionStringName)"="Server=tcp:$(ServerName).database.windows.net,1433;Database=$(DatabaseName);User ID=$(AdministratorLogin)@$(ServerName);Password=$(AdministratorLoginPassword);Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;"}` in the additional arguments of the azure deployment step.

Comment: as you can see here https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureWebPowerShellDeployment/Publish-AzureWebDeployment.ps1 it relies on Publish-AzureWebsite cmdlet any additional argument you want to pass has to correspond to one of the command's arguments.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I put in my MSBuild Arguments on a Visual Studio Build task on my build definition and it works like a champ:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True;PublishProfile="$(BuildConfiguration)" /p:publishUrl="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)" /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish
```

Note that I have BuildConfiguration as a variable which corresponds to `UAT` or `Release` or `Dev` for example. The PublishProfile corresponds to a Publish Profile you've set up in your project/solution. (So, if you name your Publish Profile "Hey-Go-To-Dev" then you'd put "Hey-Go-To-Dev" in the BuildConfiguration (or a new variable you can set up).

Anyway: This will execute your publish profile and do any related transforms in your web.config file(s).

Godspeed.